# ajax code not refresh page

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
<form id="lets_search" action="index.php" method="post" style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;" role="form" target="_blank">
      Search here: <br> </br> <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter here" style="width:400px" /> <br> </br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"class="w3-btn w3-padding"/> 
      </form>
```

Can someone be super helpful and create ajax code that makes the page not refresh the form is submitted

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a particular task. We are **not** a service to write free code for you. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you try to implement ajax youself first?

Comment: read up on [AJAX here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: You've got a new topic to learn! Why don't you make yourself happy learning something new today?

Comment: How much are you paying me?

Comment: I tried to implement it first multiple times and it did not work so thought someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<br></br>` as you don't need to close this tag; use `<br />` instead.  Additionally, I included a small example on how to use AJAX.

```js
$("#lets_search").on('submit', function () {
  $.post ("http://neil.computer/stack/ajax.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="lets_search" action="index.php" method="post" style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;" role="form" target="_blank">
Search here: <br /> <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter here" style="width:400px" /> <br />
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="w3-btn w3-padding"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: thank you this was very helpful!